# R take n observations from one dataframe to another (deal with cases when fewer observations are present)

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have two example dataframes (z1 and z2) like these:

```
City1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
z1 = data.frame(City1)

City2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3)
Tax2=c(16,93,96,44,67,73,12,10)
z2 = data.frame(City2,Tax2)
```

What I would like to do is to take the top 'n' values of Tax2 for a given City (City1 and City2 respectively) from z2 in z1. The problem is that the number of observations in the two dataframes are not same.

**Case 1:**

In the case when **nrow(z2) >= nrow(z1)** I want to take the top nrow(z1) data and put them in z1.

For eg.: For City 1: nrow(z2) = 5 and nrow(z1)=3, in this case I want to lookup the top 3 values of Tax2 from z2 and combine them in z1. This can be achieved by this code for City1:

```
cit=1
z1_data=z1[z1$City1==cit,]
z2_data=z2[z2$City2==cit,]
z2_data_sort=z2_data[order(z2_data$Tax2,decreasing = T),]
for (i in 1:nrow(z1_data)){
  z1_data[i,"Tax_lookup"]=z2_data_sort[i,"Tax2"]
}
```

**Case 2:**

But the problem arises when the reverse is true **nrow(z2) < nrow(z1)**.
In this case, I want to take the first rows from z2 and then repeat the last element for the additional observations in z1. For example if we consider City == 3:

The output I get if I run the above code for City==3 is:

```
   City1 Other_var Tax_lookup

     3         f         12
     3         g         10
     3         h         NA
```

The output I would like is:

```
   City1 Other_var Tax_lookup

     3         f         12
     3         g         10
     3         h         10 ---- **This value is repeated**
```

How would I do this in R? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just copy and paste your output. Images are generally discouraged except for plots. Please **edit** to remove images and simply copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @NelsonGon. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a little bit from [here](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2015/06/28/r-dplyr-update-rows-with-earlierprevious-rows-values/):

```
library(zoo)

z1_data %>% 
do(na.locf(.))
```